# Can a struct member be accessed if __typeof__ macro was used in declaration?

Tags: c++, g++

I compile with g++ and there are some data structures in my code:

```
typedef struct {
  int member;
  // [...]
} Record;

class Data {
  Record * records;
  // [...]
  static int method(const void * ptr);
};
```

And then the first version works:

```
int Data::method(const void * ptr) {
    Record * rec_1 = (Record *) ptr;
    return rec_1->member;
}
```

The second version does not:

```
int Data::method(const void * ptr) {
    __typeof__(records) * rec_1 = (__typeof__(records) *) ptr;
    return rec_1->member;
}
```

and throws an error:

```
error: request for member ‘member’ in ‘* rec_1’, which is of non-class type ‘Record*’
```

I the `__typeof__` macro, because it lets me not to worry of what type the `records` are. Is it possible to keep the `__typeof__` macro and be able to access the members of a struct?

Comment: Have you considered templates?

Comment: Why not just decltype or, as already mentioned, templates?

Comment: You should avoid using `__typeof__` in the first place. Then the problem would go away :)

Answer (score 3):

The `records` member is a pointer to a Record, not a Record. So you are declaring `rec_1` to be a pointer to a pointer to a Record, not the pointer to a Record that you want.

Additionally, for those trying to compile the code:

- You misspelled “typedef” as “typdef”.
- You wrote `Record->member` where you intended `rec_1->member`.
- The static member function `method` is not permitted to refer to the member `records`. Removing `static` allows it to compile.

Comment: I'm sorry for a code with typos. I just wanted to skip all the unnecessary stuff. Thanks for listing the typos, I corrected the them in the code above. And yes, the problem was I got lost at pointers.

Answer (score 2):

`records` has type `Record*`. So `rec_1` has type `Record**`.

Assuming that in your actual code the line is `rec_1->member`, not `Record->member`, then you're trying to access a member of the object `*rec_1`. But `*rec_1` has type `Record*`, it has no members.

If you post your actual code, there's a chance someone can answer your question *without* making guesses what it really says. Write the shortest program you can, that produces the compiler error you report. Indent the code by 4 spaces. Copy and paste it into your question.